# Dynamic PDF Forms CAM::PDF + PDFLib

Tags: perl, pdflib, cam-pdf

Are there any case to dynamic manage a PDF using PDFLib properties and setting form fields ?

```
my %list = ();
$doc->fillFormFields( %list );
```

[image]

Comment: Please show complete code, see [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 1):

With [PDFlib Personalization Server](https://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/pdflib-personalization-server-pps/) and the Block Plugin, you can not create interactive output like form fields. Blocks can only be of Type "textline", textflow", "image", "graphics" or"pdf".

For creating interactive form fields, you can use the PDFlib API directly. Please see the [PDFlib Cookbook -> Form Fields](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/form_fields/) for sample code.